# TableView Hides Last Row With Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, autolayout, uinavigationbar

I'm using a table view with a custom navigation controller. [EZSwipeController](https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwipeController)

The last row of the table is hidden, unless the table is dragged upward and held. Maybe the table view is being pushed down by the navigation controller? How can I set constraints so the table view is the correct size (height), taking the navigation controller into account? Thanks.

Comment: You can edit with screen shot and if possible then make demo project with above stuff and provide link from dropbox or drive, so anyone can look into it and provide you solution.

Comment: Your tableview height is wrong, try like this if you are doing it programatically => tableViewHt = self.view.height - navigationBar.ht;

Answer (score 0):

On your storyboard on that UIViewController select "Adjust Scroll View Insets".

[image]